# Apache axis2 wsdl2java exception: unknown protocol: d

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to create java files from wsdl using axis2 wsdl2java converter. The problem is that I keep getting this weird exception, which I cannot really explain.

At the moment I am using the example code in Wikipedia to test this.

Basically I call the program like this

```
wsdl2java -o "D:\Examples\SOAP" -wv 2 -uri "D:\Examples\test.wsdl"
```

And every time I get this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException
: Error parsing WSDL
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:159)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: WSDLException: faultCode=ERROR: Exception occured while reading WSDL
2.0 doc: unknown protocol: d: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown protocol: d
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.readInTheWSDL
File(WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1172)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.<init>(WSDL20
ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.<init>(WS
DL20ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:102)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: d
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.readInTheWSDL
File(WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1168)
    ... 5 more

    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.<init>(WSDL20
ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:155)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.<init>(WS
DL20ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:102)
    ... 2 more
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Edit
Exception 2:

```
Woden[Warning],0:0,Description-1001,The targetNamespace 'http://www.tmsws.com/wsdl20sample' is not dereferencable.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException
: Error parsing WSDL
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to find element {http://www.tmsws.com/wsdl20sample}request reffered to by operation Get
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.createAxisMessage(WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1112)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateOperations(WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:1053)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.processInterface(WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:956)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.processService(WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:384)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL20ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:272)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL20ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL20ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:90)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:105)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: What does the WSDL look like? Does it have any references to `d:`?

Comment: I said I use the wikipedia example at the moment, which is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wsdl

Answer (score 1):

`wsdl2java -o "D:\Examples\SOAP" -wv 2 -uri "file:/D:/Examples/test.wsdl"`

`wsdl2java` tries to read from the `D:\...` URL, you need to specify the URL (I think there is way to specify a local file instead of URL).

Comment: Still get the same exception unfortunately

Comment: @dominos Ensure that the file contains valid WSDL data and update the stacktrace in your post, please.

Comment: I don't think finding the file is the problem, because if I change wv to 1.1 then it will start complaining about description tag being used instead of definitions (which means it found the file already). There is also no need to update the stack trace as the exception stayed exactly the same when I added file: and changed slashes.

Comment: I know that your answer was about this exception. But the thing is that there are no references to d: in the wsdl file.

Comment: I just did and nothing came up.

Comment: @dominos OK, the last tip: remove `D:` from `-o` and `-uri`: `... -o /Examples/SOAP -wv 2 -uri file:/Examples/test.wsdl` and run it on disk `D:`

Comment: This one did not work. I left out the -o parameter completely and for the other one I moved test.wsdl to the same directory as wsdl2java so I could do -uri "test.wsdl". This way I managed to get some other exception, which I will add to the opening post in a moment.

Comment: Looks like it might be caused by this server tmsws.com being down... There is nothing I can do about that I guess.